# What does if(true) do?

Tags: java

What does if(true) do in this context?
I'm following a tutorial for building a chess engine. The following line of code has confused me and i'm not sure what it does exactly.

```
public class Knight extends Piece
{
    private final static int[] CANDIDATE_MOVE_COORDINATES = {-17, -15, -10 , -6, 6, 10, 15, 17};

    Knight(final int piecePosition, final Alliance pieceAlliance)
    {
        super(piecePosition, pieceAlliance);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Move> calculateLegalMoves(Board board)
    {
        int candidateDestinationCoordinate;
        final List<Move> legalMoves = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final int currentCandidate : CANDIDATE_MOVE_COORDINATES)
        {
            candidateDestinationCoordinate = this.piecePosition + currentCandidate;
            if (true)
            {
                final Tile candidateDestinationTile = board.getTile(candidateDestinationCoordinate);
                if (!candidateDestinationTile.isTileOccupied())
                {
                    legalMoves.add(new Move());
                }
                else
                {
                    final Piece pieceAtDestination = candidateDestinationTile.getPiece();
                    final Alliance pieceAlliance = pieceAtDestination.getPieceAlliance();
                    if (this.pieceAlliance != pieceAlliance)
                    {
                        legalMoves.add(new Move());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(legalMoves);
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Sometimes such is used in debugging to turn off a part of the code by switching `true` to `false`, similar to commenting out a part of the code, that's the only thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

`if(true)` just executes the code.

You can remove it, that won't have any effect.

`if(true) can be used if you want a simple way to stop execution of code at compile-time by just changing it to`if(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code `if(true)` does nothing - it is always 'true', so the code inside will always be executed, just as `if(true)` construction were not there. Please, correct me if I'm wrong, best regards